# converting vectors to raster (burning streams)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, dem, spatial-analyst

I converted my stream vector to a raster file (using polyline to raster conversion tool). I anticipated that I would get a No Data row in the raster file attribute table, so that I could use a conditional statement to burn the streams into the DEM:

con(stream_raster>0, (focalmin_dem - 2), original_dem)

However, since I did not get a No Data row, all this gives me is a a DEM img directly beneath the streams (not the remaining extent of the image).

What am I missing?

Comment: Sounds like the CON tool is honouring the NoData value. Try converting the NoData to a non stream elevation value such as -1, then run that grid through your CON tool?

Comment: Thanks, hornbydd. The problem is that I don't have anything in the stream raster grid that is NoData when I pull up the attribute table. When I converted the vector to raster, all I got was values for the cells where there are streams. So I am not able to change the NoData values to a non stream elevation value.

Comment: Could you create a polygon of the whole area, convert that to a raster, set the values to NoData, and combine the NoData raster with your stream?

Comment: I have spent a lot of the time in different blogs but this is really a unique blog for me. Excellent post. Thanks … http://www.clippingimages.com/home/services/88/raster-to-vector-conversion-

Answer (score 1):

Here is our workaround:

Generate your raster from polyline, then use the IsNull tool to set non-data cells to 1 and data cells to 0. Use this as the conditional raster in the Con tool, statement "Value" = 0, with the burn raster as the true condition and the original DEM as the false.

```
arcpy.gp.Con_sa("breach00_isnull.tif", "breach00.tif", "H:/GISdata/HUCtesting/TTR/CBBCAA_dem_b00.tif", "CBBCAA_dem.tif", """"Value" = 0""")
```